# Автозапуск кода в jupyter notebook

Tags: python, автозапуск

В процессе работы столкнулся со следующей задачей: в результате выполнения кода в jupyter notebook я получаю таблицу, которую затем отправляю в бд oracle. Хотелось бы, чтобы данные в таблице обновлялись каждый день 1 раз. Есть ли какие-то способы автозапуска программы по расписанию внутри jupyter? Если нет, то какие альтернативные решения данной задачи могут быть?

Comment: Экспортируете в py файл, и его ставите в планировщик.

Comment: jupyter notebook для этого не предназначен. вам уже посоветовали просто сохранить код в .py файл и запускать его

Comment: Ну, в принципе можно, наверное, попробовать библиотеку `scheduler`, но я не уверен, что она в `JN` работает. Хотя почему бы и нет.

Answer (score 1):

**Для Windows**

1. Экспортируйте из вашего проекта `Jupyter notebook` файл с
   расширением `.py`
2. Откройте планировщик задач через `win+R` и ввода `taskschd.msc`
3. Создайте простую задачу, в качестве триггера установите `"Ежедневно"` и выберите время, в качестве действия укажите `"Запуск программы"`, укажите путь до вашего `python.exe`, в качестве аргумента укажите `имя_вашего_файла.py`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. чтобы найти исполняемый `python.exe`, введите в `PowerShell` или `CMD` следующую команду:

```
python -c "import os, sys; print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))"
```

---

**Для Linux и MacOS**

Вы можете использовать `cron`, который является стандартным инструментом планирования задач в Unix-подобных системах. Откройте терминал и выполните команду `crontab -e`, чтобы открыть редактор `cron-задач`. Затем добавьте запись в файл, чтобы запустить ваш файл `.py` каждый день в определенное время. Например, `0 0 * * * python /путь/к/вашему/файлу.py` запустит ваш файл каждый день в полночь.